# VHDL : writing an AND function

Tags: vhdl

So im trying to write a function that performs an AND gate, the intput is a vector of the gate inputs, and the number of inputs. But for some reason the compiler gives me an error that it doesn't recognize the "and" logic operator im using inside for some reason. can anyone spot the issue?

p.s this is all part of a bigger project that is a 16counter (0-15) thats made of 4 chained JK flip flops and 2 AND gates (using my "myand" function).

```
function myand (x: std_logic_vector; n : integer range 7 downto 0) return std_logic is
    variable result: integer :=0;
begin
    for i in 0 to n-1 loop
        result:=result and x(i);
    end loop;
    return result;
end function;
```

The compiler error is:

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at counter16.vhd(16): can't determine definition of operator ""and"" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

I even tried using '+' instead of 'and' but its the same error.

Comment: Not meaning to deprecate sharth's answer or your own effort at all, IEEE Std 1076-2008 (VHDL-2008) provides unary logical operators for **and**, **or**, **nand**, **nor**, **xor**, and **xnor** referred to as logical reduction operators. These are supported for std_logic_vector (a subtype of std_ulogic_vector) and may or may not be supported a particular vendor's synthesis tool.  Recend Modelsim and the Aldec VHDL simulators would support these VHDL-2008 operators.

Answer (score 2):

The builtin libraries of VHDL don't define a operator `and` that takes a `integer` and `std_logic`.

#### How to fix this:

- `result` should be a `std_logic` instead of an `integer`.
- `result` should be initialized to `'1'` instead of `0`.

Comment: Oh man I can't believe I didn't notice trying to input 2 different types into it :P thanks! hopefully the rest will work now as well

Answer (score 1):

The function interface can be simplified by removal of the ´n´ argument if the `'range` attribute is used on `x` to get the index values.  If a subrange of a std_logic_vector is used as argument, then the `myand` function can be called with that subrange only.  Including sharth suggestions, the function is:

```
function myand (x : std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
    variable result : std_logic := '1';
begin
    for i in x'range loop
        result := result and x(i);
    end loop;
    return result;
end function;
```